# n circles and 1 straight line - divide into regions

Tags: geometry, contest-math

Original question:

> There are *n* circles and 1 straight line of a plane such that you can divide the plane into at most 44 parts. Find *n*.

So I have no idea how to do this question, the word ‘plane’ is not defined clearly.
What I mean is that, for example, refer to the picture below. Does the circle in the picture divide the plane into 1 region or 2 regions?
[image: Picture]

Comment: 2 regions: the region inside the circle and the region outside the circle.

Comment: I would say 2 regions. In your problem, there will be two unbounded parts, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $n$ circles and a line on a plane. Using a stereographic projection whose projection point is on the line but not any of the circles, we obtain $n+1$ circles on a sphere. Picking another projection point not on any of these $n+1$ circles, we get $n+1$ circles on the plane. Thus your problem is equivalent to calculating the maximal number of regions $n+1$ circles can divide a plane into. For that problem, you can check out [plane division by circles](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PlaneDivisionbyCircles.html).

Comment: As an aside, we could perform inversion about a point not on the circles or lines, to conclude that it's equivalent to calculating maximal number of regions $n+1$ circles can divide the plane into.